# Optimizing architecture of a Neural Network

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm applying NN in R with the neuralnet package.
The model prototype is performing well and now I want to generalize it by looping it over ~100 more different data-sets.

In the prototype model I have defined an architecture with 3 layers (20,10,5). The problem is that this architecture is not always performing well in the rest 100 sets,as the cross-validation error becomes quite high. For the sets the error is high I've tuned manually the model to a different architecture (10,5,5) and it improved.

How can I make the model self-adapting and finding its best architecture for each loop it makes. I'm thinking of heuristic approach by iterating the architectures (i,j,z) over each data-set, but not sure if there's a more efficient way to achieve this.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: neural architecture search

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Will test auto-keras package